# State Plane Coordinate to Latitude Longitude

Tags: dictionary, gis

I search for a C++/C# library or tool they can convert State Plane Coordinate to latitude/longitude.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you expand your question with an example of coordinates you want to convert between, and how you did it if you already solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want PROJ, the Cartographic Projections Library: https://proj.org/index.html

This used to be referred to as "PROJ4" but is now "PROJ".

Comment: Hello, Can you provide an example? I am also interested in something similar to this in the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61147814/how-to-convert-utm-coordinate-to-cartesian-coordinate-relative-to-an-earth-tange.

Comment: Examples can be found in the PROJ documentation: https://proj.org/development/quickstart.html